# Polymer 1.0: Dom-Repeat Populates With Empty Items

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

I'm probably missing something very basic. I have an array of objects. The array is a child of a property of my polymer element, implemented like so:

```
properties:
  audit:
    type: Object
    value: ()->
      return {new: [], update: []}
    notify: true
```

I want to iterate over `audit.new` with a [dom-repeat](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates).

I do that like so:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{audit.new}}" as="item">
  <div class="horizontal layout center" style="padding-bottom: 0.5em">
    <div><paper-checkbox checked="{{item.select}}" style="margin: 0px"></paper-checkbox></div>
    <div class="flex">
      <b><span>{{item.firstName}}</span>, <span>{{item.lastName}}</span></b> (<span>{{item.id}}</span>)
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Polymer renders nothing at all.

I've checked and confirmed that the array I am iterating over contains the correct data. What have I done wrong?

Comment: What is `default:      new: []      update: []` supposed to be? See https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties for how to define properties.

Comment: It's just a coffeescript implementation of the correct property hash.

Comment: Wait a minute, I used `default` instead of `value`. Oops. Let's see if that fixes it.

Comment: From my link above: " If the default value should be an array or object unique to the instance, create the array or object inside a function. "

Comment: Well, now it seems to not render anything at all

Comment: Can you update your question to show what "now" means? The question still uses `default`. I still don't know what `new` or `update` is supposed to do.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - Updated.

Comment: If you template-repeat over an empty array, why do you expect something to be rendered?

Comment: Because other parts of the code add items to the array, and I confirm that those items have been added prior to rendering.

Comment: Do you use `this.push()` Polymer API to modify the array? What exactly does "prior to rendering" mean? Does Polymer render the dom-repeat if you add an item into the default value?

Comment: Gunter - it was failure to use `this.push()`. I'm an idiot. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear you could make it work :)